# How can add integer elements inside a List?

Tags: java, arrays, list, java-7

I have a list of integers which is generated as a query result, I want to add those elements inside that array is it possible?

```
List<Objects[]> list = EnquiryService.getQuantityById(60);
```

I got the list as `list=[4,5,6]`.

How can i add elements inside my list?

Comment: You want a sum of the elements in the list?

Comment: Yeah i want the sum @Takendarkk

Comment: Do you know how to iterate a list? Like with a for loop or for-each loop?

Comment: I'm assuming the Elements will be in an `Object[]` so you could still use a for-each loop and cast to int (if you are sure they will only be integers)

Comment: Yeah its possible but cant get the sum

Comment: List<Integer> myCoords = new ArrayList<Integer>();
myCoords.add(10);
myCoords.add(20);
myCoords.add(30);
myCoords.add(40);
myCoords.add(50);

Comment: is this a list of integers or a list of Objects? Do you really need Objects in your list and can't specify the data type more precisely?

Comment: list of integers @ArthurEirich

Comment: Something is wrong with this question. You talk about a list of integers, but in your code you have a list of arrays of objects. Please edit your question to make clear what exactly you mean.

Comment: @Jesper forgot everything is it possible to add elements inside a list?

Comment: Ofcourse it's possible to add elements to a list. Just call the `add()` method on the list. But I suspect that you really mean something different, but you are not explaining clearly what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

add the elements by casting it into int.Make sure your array only consist Integer objects. you can use `(int)object`to cast from java 7

```
BigDecimal sum = new BigDecimal(0);
for(Object o:list){
   sum.add((BigDecimal)o);
}
int sumation=sum.intValueExact();
```

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Comment: use yourdecimal.intValueExact() to get the integer value

Answer (score 0):

Try Java 8 streams to sum a `List<Object[]>`:

```
BinaryOperator<Integer> integerAdder = (i, j) -> i + j;

Function<Object[], Integer> sumListOfObjects = oa -> Arrays.asList(oa)
        .stream()
        .map(o -> (Integer) o)
        .reduce(0, integerAdder);

List<Object[]> listOfObjectArrays = Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1, 2, 3},
                                                  new Integer[]{4, 5, 6});

int total = listOfObjectArrays
        .stream()
        .map(sumListOfObjects)
        .reduce(0, integerAdder);
```

Output:

```
21
```

Comment: The method stream() is undefined for the type List<Object>

Comment: What Java version are you using?

Comment: You should switch to Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a "holder" for your data.

```
List<DataHolder> list = DataHolder.getFromListOfLists(EnquiryService.getQuantityById(60));
```

You can then just call `getTotal()` on each holder.

```
public static class DataHolder {

    Object [] list;

    private int total;

    public DataHolder(Object[] list) {
        this.list = list;
        this.total = 0;

        //Sum the totals
        for (Object o:list) 
            if (o != null)
                total += (Integer)o;
    }

    //Total getter
    public int getTotal() {
        return this.total;
    }

    public static List<DataHolder> getFromListOfLists(List<Object[]> lists) {
        List<DataHolder> holders = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Object[] list:lists) {
            holders.add(new DataHolder(list));
        }
        return holders;
    }
}
```

Printing out the totals:

```
for (DataHolder holder:lists)
    System.out.println(holder.getTotal());
```